# Storing session data on memcache server

Tags: php, session, memcached

I am having problem with storing session data on a remote memcache server. This is the error i am getting:

```
[Wed Dec 14 07:33:18 2016] [error] [client 192.168.247.235] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcache). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (tcp://192.168.247.111:11211) in Unknown on line 0
```

On the same server if i try with telnet it works:

```
[root@centos ~]# telnet 192.168.247.111 11211
Trying 192.168.247.111...
Connected to 192.168.247.111.
Escape character is '^]'.
set test 0 100 3
xxx
STORED
get test
VALUE test 0 3
xxx
END
```

php.ini:

```
session.save_handler=memcache
session.save_path="tcp://192.168.247.111:11211"
```

Same thing happens when i use memcached in php.ini:

```
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path="192.168.247.111:11211"
```

just a bit more info in the error_log

```
[Wed Dec 14 07:46:02 2016] [error] [client 192.168.247.235] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Write of lock failed in /var/www/html/sess.php on line 2
[Wed Dec 14 07:46:02 2016] [error] [client 192.168.247.235] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Unable to clear session lock record in /var/www/html/sess.php on line 2
[Wed Dec 14 07:46:02 2016] [error] [client 192.168.247.235] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcached). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (192.168.247.111:11211) in Unknown on line 0
```

the php file is just 3 lines:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['somekey'] = "someval";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of testing and googling i have found that SElinux was the problem. After disabling it everything started working.